# C Linked List char array input reuse problem

Tags: c, arrays, input, linked-list, char

```
typedef struct NODE{
    char *word;
    struct NODE *next;
}node;

node *newNode(char *word) {
    node *pNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    pNode->word = word;
    pNode->next = NULL;
    return pNode;
}

void append(node **ppList, char *word) {
    if(*ppList == NULL)
        *ppList = newNode(word);
    else {
        node *tmpList = *ppList;
        for(; tmpList->next!=NULL; tmpList=tmpList->next);
        tmpList->next = newNode(word);
    }
}

void printList(node *list) {
    for(; list!=NULL; list=list->next)
        printf("[%s]=>", list->word);
    printf("NULL");
}

/*=== CODE 1 ===*/
int main() {
    char word[MAXCHAR], word2[MAXCHAR], word3[MAXCHAR];
    node *list=NULL;

    scanf("%s", &word); /* key in AAA */
    append(&list, word);
    scanf("%s", &word2); /* key in BBB */
    append(&list, word2);
    scanf("%s", &word3); /* key in CCC */
    append(&list, word3);
    printList(list);
    return 0;
}

/*=== CODE 2 ===*/
int main() {
    char word[MAXCHAR];
    node *list=NULL;

    scanf("%s", &word); /* key in AAA */
    append(&list, word);
    scanf("%s", &word); /* key in BBB */
    append(&list, word);
    scanf("%s", &word); /* key in CCC */
    append(&list, word);
    printList(list);
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs:

```
=== CODE 1 OUTPUT ===
[AAA]=>[BBB]=>[CCC]=>NULL /* it works */

=== CODE 2 OUTPUT ===
[CCC]=>[CCC]=>[CCC]=>NULL /* doesnt work, why? */
```

Hi, I am trying to loop this thing then I realized it got a wrong result. I isolated my program and I found out that the input is the problem, I tried scanf and gets both doesnt work. Why cant I use back the char array to store the input, could someone help me with this please.

Comment: You need to show how `append` function is defined and please provide [mcve].

Comment: `scanf("%s", &word);` Instead of this, try this: `scanf("%s", word);`

Comment: Voted to close because it is unclear what you are asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are assigning the pointer.

```
pNode->word = word;
```

Since `pNode->word` will always points to updated value of `word` in main. Each node in the list will have the same value.

You should copy the contents of `word` in main instead of assigning the pointer.

```
node *newNode(char *word) {
    node *pNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    pNode->word = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
    strcpy(pNode->word, word);

    pNode->next = NULL;
    return pNode;
}
```

Or

```
node *newNode(char *word) {
    node *pNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    pNode->word = strdup(word);

    pNode->next = NULL;
    return pNode;
}
```

Note: `strdup` is not `C` standard.